# Summing Cross Dates in excel

Tags: excel

I have an issue where I need to sum a criterion of ranges for cross dates. What I am trying to accomplish is basically a depreciation schedule that sums up 36 months for each month. Note: Orignal file has over 2000 lines. Example:

```
       Jan-15   Feb-15  Mar-15  Apr-15  May-15  Jun-15  Jul-15  Aug-15
Jan-15  132     123     132     123     132     123     132     123
Feb-15  132     123     132     123     132     123     132     123
Mar-15  132     123     132     123     132     123     132     123
Apr-15  132     123     132     123     132     123     132     123
May-15  132     123     132     123     132     123     132     123
Jun-15  132     123     132     123     132     123     132     123
Jul-15  132     123     132     123     132     123     132     123
Aug-15  132     123     132     123     132     123     132     123
```

This is what I have tried but it gives a `#VALUE!` error.

```
=SUMIFS(B:I,A:A,A2,B1:I1,"<"&G1)
```

Could someone help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT will work well in this instance:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:I9,(B1:I1<G1)*(A2:A9=A2))
```

Comment: Thank you this is a life saver!